# Is there a way to manipulate numbered paragraphs in Python to remove certain paragraphs which do not fall in order?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I have a string of text with numbered paragraphs from '1.' to '221.', however, there are certain paragraphs that do not follow the order and I want to remove them. Here is how the data looks:

```
text = """1. Shares of Paras Defence and Space Technologies gained 2.85 times. 
2. The company, engaged in manufacturing and testing of defence and space engineering products. 
"3. Its stock ended at Rs 499 versus issue price of Rs 175 per share.
42. On July 23, Zomato NSE 0.00 % Ltd. listed on the Indian stock exchanges.
43. That was exactly a week after the food-delivery and restaurant discovery platform's initial public offering went live. 
4. Paras Defence’s IPO, which closed on September 23, had generated bids worth Rs 38,021 crore. 
5. It surpassed the previous record of Salasar Technologies’ IPO. 
14. NBFCs are betting big time on the IPO. 
6. Paras Defence is one of the few players having an edge in defence deals."""
```

From the above text, I want to remove the content of the paragraphs which aren't in order ie. '42.', '43.' and '14'.

Output Desired:

```
relevant_text = '1. Shares of Paras Defence and Space Technologies gained 2.85 times. 
2. The company, engaged in manufacturing and testing of defence and space engineering products. 
3. Its stock ended at Rs 499 versus issue price of Rs 175 per share. 
4. Paras Defence’s IPO, which closed on September 23, had generated bids worth Rs 38,021 crore. 
5. It surpassed the previous record of Salasar Technologies’ IPO. 
6. Paras Defence is one of the few players having an edge in defence deals.'
```

I tried to match the pattern but don't know how to proceed forward. Also, I'm not sure if the regex pattern is correct as it matches '1.', '2.' etc. but not '"3.'. Here's what I came up with:

```
text_sequence = []

pattern = re.compile('(\s|["])[0-9]{1,3}\.\s')
matches = pattern.finditer(text)


for match in matches:
  for r in range(1, 999):
    if str(r) in match.group():
      text_sequence.append(match.span())
      text_sequence.append(match.group())

print(text_sequence)
```

Is there a way to get the desired output?

P.S: The matches I am getting from this code have repeated results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can match all these bullet points with a single pattern like

```py
(?s)((\d+)\. .*?)[^\w!?.…]*(?=\d+\. |\Z)
```

(see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NtqWPJ/5)) and *assuming they come in the ascending order*, then it can be solved with

```py
import re
pattern = r"((\d+)\. .*?)[^\w!?.…]*(?=\d+\. |\Z)"
text = "1. Shares of Paras Defence and Space Technologies gained 2.85 times. 2. The company, engaged in manufacturing and testing of defence and space engineering products. \"3. Its stock ended at Rs 499 versus issue price of Rs 175 per share. 42. On July 23, Zomato NSE 0.00 % Ltd. listed on the Indian stock exchanges. 43. That was exactly a week after the food-delivery and restaurant discovery platform's initial public offering went live. 4. Paras Defence’s IPO, which closed on September 23, had generated bids worth Rs 38,021 crore. 5. It surpassed the previous record of Salasar Technologies’ IPO. 14. NBFCs are betting big time on the IPO. 6. Paras Defence is one of the few players having an edge in defence deals."
result = []
idx = 1
for sent, num in re.findall(pattern, text, re.S):
    if int(num) == idx:
        result.append(sent)
        idx += 1

print("\n".join(result))
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/AJEYyl#comments). The regex matches

- `((\d+)\. .*?)` - Group 1:
- `[^\w!?.…]*` - any zero or more chars other than word, and final sentence punctuation
- `(?=\d+\. |\Z)` - a positive lookahead that requires either the end of string (`\Z`) or (`|`) one or more digits

Output:

```
1. Shares of Paras Defence and Space Technologies gained 2.85 times.
2. The company, engaged in manufacturing and testing of defence and space engineering products.
3. Its stock ended at Rs 499 versus issue price of Rs 175 per share.
4. Paras Defence’s IPO, which closed on September 23, had generated bids worth Rs 38,021 crore.
5. It surpassed the previous record of Salasar Technologies’ IPO.
6. Paras Defence is one of the few players having an edge in defence deals.
```

**NOTE**: This can be tweaked in case you have bullet points in non-ascending order if you first sort by the `num` first.

Comment: FYI, sorting can be done with `for sent, num in sorted(re.findall(pattern, text, re.S), key=lambda x: int(x[1])):`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/F6Rnw7).

Comment: This approach is definitely working better. I even found a way to skip missing bullets that works perfectly with this code.

Comment: Definitely. One of the case in which this code didn't work was with these bullet points: – 
    ....'192.', '193.', '194', '195.', '196.'.     The last pattern it matched was '192.'.       Is there a workaround for this?      [P.S: Skipping missing matches by idx+1 did not work for this.]

Comment: @AshrayaSingh I do not have your data, so I cannot check what is going on. But the regex requires a dot after the number. I do not see the dot after `194`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. There's no '.' after bullet no. 194. Also, I made a mistake, the last matched bullet is no. 193.

Comment: @AshrayaSingh Without a dot, the solution becomes rather fragile even if you make the `.` optional, like with `(?s)((\d+)\.? .*?)[^\w!?.…]*(?=\d+\.? |\Z)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
text = """1. Shares of Paras Defence and Space Technologies gained 2.85 times. 
2. The company, engaged in manufacturing and testing of defence and space engineering products. 
3. Its stock ended at Rs 499 versus issue price of Rs 175 per share.
42. On July 23, Zomato NSE 0.00 % Ltd. listed on the Indian stock exchanges.
43. That was exactly a week after the food-delivery and restaurant discovery platform's initial public offering went live. 
4. Paras Defence’s IPO, which closed on September 23, had generated bids worth Rs 38,021 crore. 
5. It surpassed the previous record of Salasar Technologies’ IPO. 
14. NBFCs are betting big time on the IPO. 
6. Paras Defence is one of the few players having an edge in defence deals."""
lines = text.split("\n")
output = ""
i = 0
for l in lines:
    if (l.startswith("{}. ".format(i+1))):
        output+=l+"\n"
        i+=1
        
print(output)
```

Provided you get rid of the extra " in line 3. You can also consider using "in" instead of "startswith" if you can guarantee that the line number followed by a dot is not in the string.

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason, it is giving a blank string. It could be because the string 'text' does not have newlines as I have just added them here for better readability.

Comment: That would do it, the code worked on my machine but I used line breaks.

Comment: Yes, it works with this test text string with line breaks but not with the original string. Is there a way to make this work without the inherent line breaks in the string?